# paramiko SFTP hangs on get

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to use paramiko to get a file via SFTP.
It connects, I can list directories and it even downloads the first megabyte or so of the file but then it just hangs. No exception, no error, nothing. It just hangs there indefinitely.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import paramiko
t = paramiko.Transport( host )
t.connect( username=uname, password=passwd )
f = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport( t )
print f.listdir()
f.get( fname, fname ) #it hangs on this line :\
```

I have sftp access to the host in question but no shell access.
The host contains a single file that I need to fetch regularly and process in a python script.

Any help with this problem or alternate solutions to doing SFTP in Python are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the same problem as Ulfur. He posted his own fix/workaround as a comment to another answer, so I decided to add it as a proper answer to make it more visible.

The basic idea is to *not* use the `.get()` method, but to loop over the lines. The following is a Python 3 implementation.

```
transport = None
sftp = None

sftp_path = 'some/sftp/path'
dst_path = '/some/local/path'

try:
    transport = paramiko.Transport((SFTP_HOST, SFTP_PORT))
    transport.set_log_channel('delapi')
    transport.connect(username=SFTP_USER, password=SFTP_PASS)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    with sftp.open(sftp_path, 'r') as remote:
        with open(dst_path, 'w') as local:
            for line in remote:
                local.write(line)

except SSHException:
    print("SSH error")
finally:
    if sftp:
        sftp.close()
    if transport:
        transport.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was first struggling with the same symptom when I was using pysftp which is building up on paramiko. Following your approach helped me download files from an old legacy system.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fire up Wireshark on the client and see what's happening at the protocol level.  You won't be able to read the data in the packets as it will be encrypted, but you will see what's going on at the TCP/IP level and that might provide a clue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I set up Wireshark (didn't know ethereal had been force to change names) and ran a capture for the duration which my program was actually downloading stuff. However, I'm afraid I'm not well versed enough in low level ssh and tcp to be able make much sense of it. There don't really seem to be any errors though, it just seems to just stop!

Comment: Can you upload the capture file to a server where we can download it for examination?

Comment: Here you go: http://drop.io/ulfur_dump
Hope it helps, I'm totally stumped by this problem :\

Comment: Well, your side seems to receive and acknowledge data packets normally. Then, at packet 1631 it sends a request packet and gets no response from the server.  It waits 16 seconds and then closes the connection.  Can you look at the server logs to see if anything's amiss there?

Comment: Exactly, that wait at packet 1631 is the "hang" I talked about.
The connection closing was me killing the process because it would have waited indefinitely if I hadn't. Unfortunately I don't have access to the logs on the server in question so I can't check them. All I have is SFTP access to a single directory.

I guess I'll have to contact support on the server side and see if they can figure it out. I'll post here if anything comes out of it.

Comment: Well, I didn't contact support so the original issue is still not resolved.

However, I kept at the code and decided to try a different approach.
The code is now:

import paramiko
t = paramiko.Transport( host )
t.connect( username=uname, password=passwd )
f = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport( t )
#f.get( fname, fname ) #it hangs on this line :\
local = open( fname, 'w' )
remote = f.open( fname, 'r' )
for line in remote.xreadlines():
  local.write( line )
local.close()
remote.close()
f.close()
t.close()

And this works so this is what I'll use for now.
Thanks for your help though Jim :)